# Could I create a MFC DLL for Metro apps to use?

Tags: dll, microsoft-metro

I've post this question on MSDN (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/9da1b0e4-6a03-41b2-b68e-6fefb4729c52). If it is considered as duplicated question, please remind me to delete it. Thanks.

I am using VS2012 pro on Win8 Pro. I encountered an issue and needs your help:

Let me simplify the scenario: Metro App (JavaScript) calls DLL1(a Windows Runtime Component), and DLL1 calls DLL2(a MFC DLL).

After I created a MFC DLL, then from "Configuration Properties", I changed the "use of MFC" as "Use Standard Windows Libraries", and changed "Windows Store App Support" as "Yes". But My Metro App always said that "0x8007007e - JavaScript runtime error: The specified module could not be found." After debugging, I found that the error is caused by DLL2. But I don't know why it is caused.

Does anybody know anything about this? Or would you please give me some hint?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary to add my solution: I must manually add the external dependent dll  (not the system dll but built by yourself or others) into my js project by "added as link". Thus the issue could be resolved. If any encounter the same issue, please write to me and let's discuss it. Thanks.